# How to toggle content without "hidden div" or "display none"?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out how to do something that I would think would be very simple, but has proven to be quite a task to figure out.  I want to use javascript to toggle certain content so someone has to click on a link for it to display.  However, I would prefer to use javascript without having to add a hidden div or set the display to none in the CSS since search engines can recognize that as hidden content and punish your rankings for that.

Does anyone know how to safely do this with javascript?

For example, if someone clicks on "this is my link", then the content "here is my content" would appear?

Comment: Consider ellaborating a bit more on your question. Its a bit broad. For a simple method, `function switchContent () { getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = "my content" }` and then `<button onClick="switchContent()">My button</button>`

Comment: You could include your SEO keywords in white text on a white background. It'll be just like 1995 again.

Comment: Search engines still look for off-screen text or same colour font, so really [the point is moot](http://youtu.be/EsW8E4dOtRY). For more information, see [Google's content guidelines on hidden text](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66353?hl=en).

Comment: you can leave the content as it is and then hide it on pageLoad with js, since search engines don't execute js your content wont be hidden for them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other ways to "hide" content. Without using `display: none` or `visibility: hidden` or even mangling with the widths or heights. Consider the following CSS:

```
.hidden {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Use the `text-indent` to push the text out of the div's box, don't let white-space wrap text and hide any overflow of text.

If your HTML is like this:

```
<a href="#" class="trigger">this is my link</a>
<div class="content hidden">here is my content</div>
```

Then the Javascript to enable show/hide will just add/remove the class name (this example is using jQuery):

```
var $content = $('.content');
$('.trigger').click(function(e) {
    if ($content.hasClass('hidden')) {
        $content.removeClass('hidden');
    } else {
        $content.addClass('hidden');
    }
});
```

See this in action http://jsfiddle.net/amyamy86/45s9N/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could target the z-index and bring the hidden content forward and ontop of a background layer which hides it? Another method is to set the width+height to 0px and expand it onclick of your link. You could also try the left+top settings to move the content offscreen or even the opacity setting might work. The choice is yours.